# How to determine shift+alt+control+menu keys pressed win8 metro app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I am working on a project and I have some textboxes some of them digits only but in xaml inputscope="number" the virtual keyboard appears with some characters too like "[ + % ]" .... 
I used key.down event but shift+4 (+) is passed the exeception
I searched and found control.modiferKey but its not on metro app

I think that

```
if keyDown is shift boolean = true 
if keyUp boolean = false 
if boolean == true and digit pressed do nothing
```

but there must be a simple way 
can anyone help me?

Comment: Use CoreWindow.GetKeyState() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to the constructor it will handle a global key down and key

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
        Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += CoreWindow_KeyUp;
```

heres their events

```
void CoreWindow_KeyUp(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        //this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        var key = args.VirtualKey;
        string aa = args.ToString();
    }

    void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        //this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        var key = args.VirtualKey;
        string aa = args.ToString();
    }
```

you can ahndle your own logic inside this event. Most of the ky down event can be captured like dis ... Please try implementing the code and see

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void pwd_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            loginclick_Click(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
        }
    }
```

instead of enter do shift,ctrl etc